# How to receive UDP message concurrently over all threads

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, networking, udp

When working on a bigger project that included multithreading and UDP I noticed that the messages were all over the place. The initial plan was that every message has a header and all the threads receive it at the same time, now which thread ignores it and which one accepts depends on the header. So i wrote the following simple code just to check

client.py

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

inpt = input("Enter input: ")

s.sendto(inpt.encode(), ("127.0.0.1", 50005))
```

server.py

```
import socket, threading

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

s.bind(("127.0.0.1", 50005))

def thrd1():
    msg = s.recv(1024).decode()
    print(f"thread 1: {msg}")

def thrd2():
    msg = s.recv(1024).decode()
    print(f"thread 2: {msg}")

t1 = threading.Thread(target=thrd1)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=thrd2)

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

The expected result was that when i write a message both thread 1 and thread 2 give an output at the same time, however when sending a message only thread 1 gave an output and thread 2 waited for a second message.

Is there anything i can change in this code to make it work as intended?

Comment: A message will only be returned by one `recv()` call. If there are multiple threads blocked in `recv()` when a message arrives, an arbitrary one will process it.

Comment: You should have a main thread that receives each message, and worker threads that process them. The main thread can distribute the message to the appropriate workers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get the behavior you want is to provide each receiving thread with its own UDP socket, and send broadcast (or multicast) UDP packets instead of unicast.  Like this:

```
// server.py
import socket, threading

def createReceivingSocket():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEPORT, 1)
    s.bind(("", 50005))
    return s

def thrd1():
    s = createReceivingSocket()
    while True:
       msg = s.recv(1024).decode()
       print(f"thread 1: {msg}")

def thrd2():
    s = createReceivingSocket()
    while True:
       msg = s.recv(1024).decode()
       print(f"thread 2: {msg}")

t1 = threading.Thread(target=thrd1)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=thrd2)
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
```

and here is the updated client code:

```
// client.py
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, socket.IP_TTL, 0) # to keep the packets off the LAN
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)

inpt = input("Enter input: ")
s.sendto(inpt.encode(), ("<broadcast>", 50005))
```